# opencv function "convertPointsFromHomogeneous" gives error message "Either the number of channels or columns or rows must be =1"

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use method `convertPointsFromHomogeneous` as follows:

```
Mat coord(1, 3, CV_32F, Scalar(3)),
    homo;
cout<<coord<<endl
    <<coord.channels()<<", "<<coord.size()<<endl;
cv::convertPointsFromHomogeneous(coord, homo);
```

`cout` gives me:

```
[3, 3, 3]
1, [3 x 1]
```

while `convertPointsFromHomogeneous` gets me the error message:

> OpenCV Error: Incorrect size of input array (Either the number of
>   channels or columns or rows must be =1) in
>   cvConvertPointsHomogeneous, file ......\modules\c
>   alib3d\src\fundam.cpp, line 865

the var `coord` has only one row, so where exactly is the error occurred?

---

And I tracked into the source code *fundam.cpp*, line 862:

```
else
{
    if( !((src->rows > 1) ^ (CV_MAT_CN(src->type) > 1)) )
        CV_Error( CV_StsBadSize, "Either the number of channels or columns or rows must be =1" );

    s_dims = CV_MAT_CN(src->type)*src->rows;
    s_count = src->cols;
}
```

the var `src->rows` is `1`, and `src->type` is `0x42424005`, which makes `CV_MAT_CN(src->type)` being `1`, so I suspect the logic is wrong, is that true?

Comment: @sansuiso yes, and it's `CV_32F` making the Mat have 1 channel.

Comment: careful: `Mat coord(1, 3, CV_32F, 3)` // your last '3' is interpreted as a *pointer*, make it 3.0 if you want some init value

Comment: @berak, isn't `3` parsed as `Scalar(3)`? BTW, I've posted the same question on answers.opencv.org, but it seems disappeared (not shown in my profile page), do you know what happened?

Comment: ^^ there is a conversion, but the compiler will prefer the uchar* cast. (and yes, answers.opencv.org has some problems atm. due to a spam attack, they switched to 'moderation', so anything horribly delayed there );

Comment: Do you still have the issue by typing `Mat coord(1, 3, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(3));` ?

Comment: weird thing is, that the problem still shows, if we omit the last param totally (leave the mat uninitialized)

Comment: @sansuiso, yes I tried, and see my edits

Comment: @berak, don't you think the XOR logic `^` here is wrong?

Comment: It looks more and more like a bug, doesn't ?